# Test/track mobile data speed by location

Tags: android, gps

Basically I want to plot the black spots of no mobile internet in an area. Eg I would like an app that can constantly ping or test internet connection as I move around in a car then GPS log each result, so I can see on a map where the black spots are.

Comment: Not for internet strength but general signal strength, you can find a bunch of mapping apps [in my list here](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/network_cellsignal#group_403). Not sure if any of them would also cover internet quality.